# "Parameters or Publish" which method best suits to pass parameters to a canvas app from a visualforce page?

Tags: canvas

I understand from the documentation that we can pass parameters to canvas app using the parameters attribute of `<apex:canvasApp` visualforce tag.

Also using the canvas javascript sdk we can publish the data from visualforce page so that the canvas app can subscribe to it.

But i am wondering which method best suits to pass parameters to a canvas app from a visualforce page and what is the advantage of one over other? And any differences between these methods. How does the communication between vf page and canvas app differs with parameters and publish? Pleas suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Canvas Javascript publish is an event](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_app_events.htm). You can trigger it multiple times and vary the payload each time. Your canvas app needs to subscribe to these events to receive them. You can also publish events from the canvas app back to the Visualforce page.

The [`<apex:canvasApp>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_app_vf_component_ref.htm) parameters in contrast are fixed at the time the page is rendered and are one way (Visualforce Page to Canvas App). You can read these parameters out of the signed request that is sent to the canvas app.

So, if you need interaction between the canvas app and its container the events will be required. If the data is fixed, the signed request parameters will be easier as you don't need to subscribe to events and then raise the events from the container.